# SQL Server Join 2 Tables with Relationship in 3rd Table

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
Table_A
tblA_ID | tblA_Key | tblA_Info
1         2A         ABC

Table_B
tblB_ID | tblB_to_A_Relations | tblB_Info
1         1                     XYZ
2         1                     DEF
3         1                     QWE
4         1                     NOP

Table_C
tblC_ID | tblC_to_A_Relations | tblC_Info
1         2A                    999
2         2A                    888
3         2A                    777
```

Table_B and Table_C doesn't have direct relationship but I wanted to join them by using their relationships on Table_A. This is what I've tried so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    b.*,
    c.tblC_Info,                                        
FROM Table_B b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblA_ID, tblA_Key FROM Table_A
        WHERE tblA_Key = @parameter)a
ON a.tblA_ID = b.tblB_to_A_Relations
LEFT JOIN Table_C c
ON c.tblC_to_A_Relations = a.tblA_Key
ORDER BY b.tblB_ID ASC
```

Somehow outputs:

```
ResultSet
tblB_ID | tblB_to_A_Relations | tblB_Info | tblC_Info
1         1                     XYZ         999
1         1                     XYZ         888
1         1                     XYZ         777
2         1                     DEF         999
2         1                     DEF         888
2         1                     DEF         777
3         1                     QWE         999
3         1                     QWE         888
3         1                     QWE         777
4         1                     NOP         999
4         1                     NOP         999
4         1                     NOP         999
```

But my expected output is something like this:

```
ExpectedOutput
tblB_ID | tblB_to_A_Relations | tblB_Info | tblC_Info
1         1                     XYZ         NULL
2         1                     DEF         999
3         1                     QWE         888
4         1                     NOP         777
```

Surely missing something. Any help would really be appreciated!

**EDIT**

After more inspection of the existing tables and data, it appears that the above results are already filtered records and luckily, after tedious tracing, I found a field that somehow tells them they are unique from the other records.

```
Table_B
tblB_ID | tblB_to_A_Relations | tblB_Info | **tblB_Values**
1         1                     XYZ         AAA
2         1                     DEF         BBB
3         1                     QWE         CCC
4         1                     NOP         DDD

Table_C
tblC_ID | tblC_to_A_Relations | tblC_Info | **tblC_Values**
1         2A                    999         BBB
2         2A                    888         CCC
3         2A                    777         DDD
```

At first, I made a mistake to ignore these fields not knowing the answer was there all along.

Going to post my answer.

Comment: In your db you just don't have such relation that you want to get. Can you explain how `tblB_Info = DEF` shold match **ONLY** `tblC_Info = 999` and not any other? You can't get this info from your db scheme.

Comment: You're getting duplicates from your relationship between table A and table C. Each table C key ID in table A has 3 values

Comment: I also tried to produce a modified resultset for `Table_B` with an additional `tblB_Modified_Field` and values of `tblA_key`, I still get the same result as above. How so?

Comment: Your expected output is not possible in your current model, the relation between B and C is missing. Add column TblB_ID to tableC or add column TblC_id to tableB or add tblc_info tob tableB and drop tableC.

Comment: Why there is `NULL` in your expected query in row tblB_ID = 1 ? what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: I know this seems a bit of a mess but these are existing data needed for reports. The null value is necessary because the requirements of the first entry should be non-existent. I guess I have to produce temporary containers to make this work. Gonna try other workarounds and will post any updates.

Comment: @am0r  If this is how your data is structured, you need to either tell whoever is asking for this report that it isn't possible or you need to rethink your database design and make changes so that it is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I figured I had to create a relationship (1:1 Relationship per record) in a temporary view to produce what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare  @A table
(
tbla_ID int,
tblA_Key  varchar(2),
tbla_info varchar(3)
)
Declare  @B table
(
tblb_ID int,
tblB_to_A  varchar(2),
tblB_info varchar(3)
)
Declare  @C table
(
tblb_ID int,
tblC_to_A  varchar(2),
tblB_info int
)

Insert into @A
Select 1,'2A','ABC'

Insert into @B
Select 1,1,'XYZ'
union
Select 2,1,'DEF'
union
Select 3,1,'QWE'
union
Select 4,1,'NOP'

Insert into @c
Select 1,'2A',999
UNION
Select 2,'2A',888
UNION
Select 3,'2A',777


Select B.*,C.tblB_info from @A A
join @B B
on A.tbla_ID=B.tblB_to_A
left join @C C
on B.tblb_ID=C.tblb_ID and A.tbla_key=C.tblC_to_A
```

Null value belongs to 4th row exactly equal to 'NOP'

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I did:

Create a temporary container and update unique keys from Table_B to Table_C in a modified column of a temporary table with reference to Table_A.

Here's what the temporary table looked like:

```
TempTbl
tblC_ID | Modified_Col | tblC_to_A_Relations | tblC_Info
1         2              2A                    999
2         3              2A                    888
3         4              2A                    777
```

Managed to get this resultset using a copy of Table_C (#TempTbl)

```
UPDATE #TempTbl
SET
    #TempTbl.Modified_Col = #TempTbl_B.tblB_ID 
    FROM
    #TempTbl
    INNER JOIN
    #TempTbl_B
    ON
    #TempTbl.tblB_Values = #TempTbl_B.tblC_Values
```

And pulled left join for final result.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_B x
LEFT JOIN #TempTbl y
ON x.tblB_ID = y.Modified_Col
```

PS: I really do apologize how horrible the workaround was.